# how do i stop my jframe randomizer from just shaking

Tags: java, swing

i created a program that makes a cube randomly move but how do i stop it from just shaking and actually make it move?

```
import java.awt.Color;


import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.random.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
public class AIcivilication{

    private static final JPanel island = new JPanel();
    
    private static final JPanel character = new JPanel();
     here`import java.awt.Color;



    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public static void area(){
        int y = 120;
         int x = 100;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        KeyEvent e = null;
        movementthinking();
        frame.setTitle("civilication");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(2000,700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);

        
        
        character.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        character.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50);
        frame.add(character);
        
        
    }

        
        public static void movementthinking() {
        
            
            
            
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                 Timer timer = new Timer(5/120,new MyActionListener());
                    timer.start();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
            
            
            
            
        }
        
        
        
    

    
        public static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { 
                Random r = new Random();
                int de = r.nextInt(3);
                
                 int y =350;
                 int x = 750;
                if(de == 0) {
                    
                    character.setLocation(x, y+=10);
                    
                }
                if(de == 1) {
                    
                character.setLocation(x, y-=10);
                
            }
                if(de == 2) {
                    character.setLocation(x+=10, y);
                    
                }
                if(de == 3) {
                    character.setLocation(x-=10, y);
                    
                
                }}
            

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    area();

                }
            });
        }
        

}
```

it picks number from 0 - 3 then go to a random direction but it looks like a shaking cube. how do i stop it from shaking like that and move to diffrent directions with the correct animations?

Comment: Your Random instance is not picking a number from 0 to 3 but rather from 0 to 2 (`Random#nextInt(3)` is from 0 to 2 inclusive). But if you fix this, you will get essentially "Brownian motion", which is almost what you're seeing. Random buffeted movements.

Comment: how do i stop the "Brownian motion" from happening?

Comment: Well, what *kind* of motion do you want? Your code just says to move your sprite 1 pixel in a random direction with each iteration. What do you ***want*** to happen?

Comment: 10 pixels of movement is not a lot, so it might indeed just look like shaking. Have you tried picking a higher distance (maybe random as well)? Another thing is - `5/120` is in milliseconds, and thats not a lot by human reaction times either. I'm positive that by changing these two numbers you will fix your animation woes eventually.

Comment: Other unrelated suggestions: 1) Best to get most of that code *out* of the static world and into the instance world.  2) Best to post well-formatted code when you are asking others to review it and help you. No sense in making it harder to read and understand than necessary.

Comment: Perhaps what you want to do is not change the sprites *position* with each tick but rather its *direction*. If that is the case, then you need to think of directional vectors, and this will require some trigonometry.

Comment: srry @HovercraftFullOfEels im kinda new :)

Comment: I understand, but don't apologize. Instead [edit] and fix the question and its code.

Comment: Also, if you move a JPanel, you must call `repaint()` on the container that holds it after moving it. But I recommend that you *not* do this. Instead, draw a sprite within a stationary drawing JPanel's paintComponent method and animate the sprite. You still need to call `repaint()` but now on the JPanel that is doing the drawing. Also, avoid null layouts and instead use the layout managers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i dont know triginometry im only a 8th grader do you know any yt trigonometry intro

Comment: @EnzoSebastian, no, sorry, I do not. I learned it in school myself, years, and years, and ***years*** ago.